# Changed redirect path, local and azure

Tags: azure

Using local path, it redirects to :

```
http://localhost:3979/api/OAuthCallback
```

But it works only for me (locally)

I'am trying to access same location like this :

```
http://myapp.azurewebsites.net/api/OAuthCallback
```

But it throws an error ....
How to handle this ?

Comment: What is the error? Can you show your auth configuration? Have you registered both reply URLs in Azure AD? Actually, are you using Azure AD or some other OAuth provider?

Comment: No. I am using facebook authentication.

Comment: Have you checked the azure URL was added to the valid reply URLs? Quoting from FB docs: "You can confirm that this URL is set for your app by going to the App Dashboard, clicking Facebook Login in the right-hand menu, and checking the Valid OAuth redirect URIs in the Client OAuth Settings section."

Comment: Ok. I found what was the problem. Get method with parameters. I was trying to make request without parameters.